# Verilog: Can I omit the length of a register that is initialised to a string?

Tags: verilog

In Verilog, one can work with strings as follows:

```
reg test [12 * 8 - 1:0] = "Hello world!";
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler to simply have a `reg` of the appropriate length similar to C?

```
reg test [] = "Hello world!";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SystemVerilog, we can simply use the string data type:

```
string hello = "Hello world!"
```

But in Verilog your first line is still the best option:

```
reg test [12 * 8 - 1:0] = "Hello world!";
```

---

EDIT:
For synthesis, even in SystemVerilog, it is much safer to do something like this:

```
parameter CSIZE = 8;
parameter CCOUNT = 80;
reg [CCOUNT * CSIZE – 1 : 0] heythere = “Hello, world!”;
```

Comment: I'm happy to use SystemVerilog! Is it synthesisable?

Comment: Some tools will turn strings into a sequence of bits; however, alternative 2 is a much safer/reliable/portable way to do this. See my edit.